# sudo to remember password for list of commands?

Tags: command-line, sudo

Is there a way in Linux to make *sudo* command to remember the password the user entered for in the first of the lines?

For example, for a list of commands that the user has to enter, the some of then requiring a *sudo* prefix, how can one make sure that if the user copy+pastes the instructions into a terminal all in one go, is only asked the password once?

Example:

```
mkdir ~/acpiinfo ; cd ~/acpiinfo
sudo acpidump > acpidump.txt
# enter password 
sudo acpixtract acpidump.txt
ls *.dat | while read i; do iasl -d "${i}"; done
pid=`sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name`
vid=`sudo dmidecode -s system-version`
name=$pid.$vid
mkdir "${name}" && cp *.dsl "${name}"/ 
tar czf "${name}.tar.gz" "${name}"/ && ls -l "$( pwd )/${name}".tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double sudo is [not necessary](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/95a14b4cfc8fd9b0c393f79d3476a5fa778ac7a7/.bash_aliases#L22):

```
sudo sh -c "apt-get update && apt-get -y dist-upgrade && apt-get -y autoremove && apt-get autoclean"
```

This works fine even if one command can take very long.

Answer (score 9):

It should do this by default.  From the sudo manpage:

> Once a user has been authenticated, a time stamp is updated and the
>   user may then use sudo without a password for a short period of time
>   (5 minutes unless overridden in sudoers).

If your system is not doing this, maybe check `/etc/sudoers`.  From the sudoers manpage:

> timestamp_timeout
>
> > Number of minutes that can elapse before sudo will ask
> >     for a passwd again.  The timeout may include a
> >     fractional component if minute granularity is
> >     insufficient, for example 2.5.  The default is 5.  Set
> >     this to 0 to always prompt for a password.  If set to a
> >     value less than 0 the user's timestamp will never
> >     expire.  This can be used to allow users to create or
> >     delete their own timestamps via sudo -v and sudo -k
> >     respectively.

So it sounds like the `timestamp_timeout` variable may have been set to 0.  Fire up `visudo` and comment that line out or set it to something of your liking.

Answer (score 1):

The `sudo bash -c 'sudo cmd1; cmd2; sudo cmd3;...'` idiom seems to remember the password for a list of commands.

```
# test cases
sudo bash -c 'sudo ls -ld *; sleep 500; sudo ls -ld *'
sudo -k
sudo bash -c 'sudo ls -ld *; sudo -k; sleep 5; sudo ls -ld *'
```

Comment: This doesn't remember the password for a list or series of commands, it just crams everything into one command.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo -s` will start a shell as root ( possibly prompting you for your password ).  You can then enter several commands without the need to prefix them with sudo.  When finished, `exit` the root shell.

Comment: is it the same as `sudo su`?

Comment: @動靜能量, yes, only without running two programs.